# How to upgrade PostgreSQL from 14 to 15 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04, postgresql

I have Ubuntu 22.04. I currently have PostgreSQL 14.6. I want to upgrade PostgreSQL to 15. I tried running:

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install postgresql
```

but I got the following message:

```
...
postgresql is already the newest version (14+238.pgdg21.04+1).
```

How do I upgrade PostgreSQL from 14 to 15 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PostgreSQL 15 is not available in the default package repository. To install PostgreSQL >= 15, you need to add an additional APT repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

In order to do so, run:

```bash
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget -qO- https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pgdg.asc &>/dev/null
```

Then,

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql
```

It worked:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 15.2 (Ubuntu 15.2-1.pgdg22.04+1)
```

---

Source: https://www.linuxtechi.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu/

Comment: If I may make a suggestion, it's generally considered poor form to use `trusted.gpg.d` to define trusted keys, and instead to make `/etc/apt/keyrings`, store the PGP keys there, and then add a source with the signed key of `deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/FILENAME] ...` instead nowadays, which defers from the 'guides' but makes things a little more 'secure' (so that the pgp key for the PSQL repos can't be used to sign *other* repos)

Comment: `$ psql --version` isn't the server version. It's the client version. To check server version, you need to connect and then `select version();`

Answer (score 3):

Or, alternately, as noted by [Thomas Ward -On Strike](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456014/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-from-14-to-15-on-ubuntu-22-04#comment2545261_1456015), if you would want to do it the secure way, you could simply run this [script](https://salsa.debian.org/postgresql/postgresql-common/raw/master/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.sh) provided from PostgreSQL [itself.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt)

Answer (score 1):

For bionic, both solutions listed lead to a 404 error for me, like:

> The repository 'https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.

The repos were moved to the archive, so I needed to update the URL to:
https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt.

Ex:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt-archive.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget -qO- https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pgdg.asc &>/dev/null
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77443882/2514961